# Best practice for setting up different environments with Amazon web service

Tags: architecture, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We are restructuring our environments by removing some microsoft servers/instances/hardware and move into Amazon cloud web service (e.g. DynamoDB)

I know the Amazon charges the service based on the usage of the service, it makes sense for production environment, but we have dev, systest, uat environments that need to move to cloud as well and we don't want the company paid money for the usage due to internal development or testing process.

Is there any best practice that can avoid/reduce cost

Thanks

Ming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EC2 instances used for development purposes can be started/stopped when needed to help save costs. As mentioned, AWS does have a free usage tier but some of the free quotas expire after one year (see http://aws.amazon.com/free/ for details).

[Eucalyptus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus_%28computing%29) provides an S3-compatible implementation that you can test against locally.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what exactly does the "750 hours free usage" for EC2 mean. Is the usage calculated by summing up of the usage of all my instances. For example, if I have 2 instances running every hours every day, then I would need to pay ((2 * 24 hours * days of the month) - 750) * fee per hour???

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has "free tier" pricing for most services that allows you to do a lot of development free of charge (assuming you aren't doing any high volume load testing or testing large data sets...)

Answer (score 0):

With Dynamo you get 5 reads / writes free - enough for one table, I have 10 active tables all set at 5 / 5 and I think it costs around $30 / month which certainly doesn't break the bank. EC2 micro instance is completely free and should be more than enough for your transitioning period.